# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 - APK size too low

Tags: android, android-studio

There is some problem, while generating APK with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3. The APK size is very low when compared with Android Studio 2.3.2

**Android Studio 3.0:**
 It runs directly on device with USB debugging enabled(7.8 MB). 
 But it didn't get installed when I shared it via Fabric(4 MB). It happens both with debug and release APK.

**Android Studio 2.3.2:**
Works well with USB debugging enabled and Fabric.

Attaching the screenshot of generated APK file size.
[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `"But it didn't get installed when i [...]"`, why?

Comment: I don't know why?

Comment: so how you know it is not installed?

Comment: When I click install from Fabric's Beta App. It didn't get installed . I can see it

Comment: How are you generating the apk? Just hitting Run? If so it could be that you have Instant Run enabled on 3.0 but not 2.3. This would result in just a partial apk being built.